# Dreambooth - RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0

Tags: python, tensor

I'm trying to train a model via Dreambooth and I'm running into this problem. I've looked for solutions but none of them seem to work. I read adding ".to(device)" to variables helps but I'm not sure where to add them. I was wondering if anyone could tell where to add them by the error below, or if anyone had suggestions on how to fix it. I'm a beginner, so please bear with me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 835, in <module>
    trainer.fit(model, data)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 741, in fit
    self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 686, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 778, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1200, in _run
    self._dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1280, in _dispatch
    self.training_type_plugin.start_training(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\plugins\training_type\training_type_plugin.py", line 202, in start_training
    self._results = trainer.run_stage()
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1290, in run_stage
    return self._run_train()
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1312, in _run_train
    self._run_sanity_check(self.lightning_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\trainer\trainer.py", line 1376, in _run_sanity_check
    self._evaluation_loop.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\loops\base.py", line 145, in run
    self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\loops\dataloader\evaluation_loop.py", line 110, in advance
    dl_outputs = self.epoch_loop.run(dataloader, dataloader_idx, dl_max_batches, self.num_dataloaders)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\loops\base.py", line 145, in run
    self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\loops\epoch\evaluation_epoch_loop.py", line 122, in advance
    output = self._evaluation_step(batch, batch_idx, dataloader_idx)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\loops\epoch\evaluation_epoch_loop.py", line 217, in _evaluation_step
    output = self.trainer.accelerator.validation_step(step_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\accelerators\accelerator.py", line 236, in validation_step
    return self.training_type_plugin.validation_step(*step_kwargs.values())
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\pytorch_lightning\plugins\training_type\training_type_plugin.py", line 219, in validation_step
    return self.model.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 28, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 368, in validation_step
    _, loss_dict_no_ema = self.shared_step(batch)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 908, in shared_step
    loss = self(x, c)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 937, in forward
    c = self.get_learned_conditioning(c)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\models\diffusion\ddpm.py", line 595, in get_learned_conditioning
    c = self.cond_stage_model.encode(c, embedding_manager=self.embedding_manager)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 324, in encode
    return self(text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 319, in forward
    z = self.transformer(input_ids=tokens, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 297, in transformer_forward
    return self.text_model(
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 258, in text_encoder_forward
    hidden_states = self.embeddings(input_ids=input_ids, position_ids=position_ids, embedding_manager=embedding_manager)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Dreambooth-SD-optimized\ldm\modules\encoders\modules.py", line 180, in embedding_forward
    inputs_embeds = self.token_embedding(input_ids)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py", line 158, in forward
    return F.embedding(
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2044, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

there are a whole bunch of functions in SD that WILL NOT work if you're running --lowvram/--medvram and several of the other command line args. tensors on multiple devices means due to your settings you're at least partially co-processing on your cpu. to test which setting, if you're not sure, don't waste time in dreambooth to troubleshoot, use the textual inversion trainer. it'll trigger the same crash for the same reasons. i have to disable --medvram just to create an embedding, so use that as your troubleshooter. try to create an embedding, change settings, repeat, till you find all the options triggering the cpu/cuda error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33086632)